# Kafka GlobalStreamThread shuts down without giving any relevant information in the logs

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We have a Kafka streams application which is using Kafka streams GlobalStreamingThread. Changelog is not enabled. As expected, the application is firstly [restoring the global state store](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/internals/GlobalStateManagerImpl.java#L205-L216) but it fails during restoration of state and doesn't log any relevant error messages for the failure.

The first message seen is "Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions" .

After enabling debug logging the only logs we see are:

```
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:42,950 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher:1235 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Added READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch request for partition hidden-topic-name-59 at position FetchPosition{offset=809302, offsetEpoch=Optional[85], currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[b-2.pdx-lev-d01-c0-amak-ch.ghdxjf.c3.kafka.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:9096 (id: 2 rack: usw2-az3)], epoch=108}} to node b-2.pdx-lev-d01-c0-amak-ch.ghdxjf.c3.kafka.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:9096 (id: 2 rack: usw2-az3)
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:42,950 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.FetchSessionHandler:351 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Built incremental fetch (sessionId=749023988, epoch=275) for node 2. Added 0 partition(s), altered 1 partition(s), removed 0 partition(s), replaced 0 partition(s) out of 1 partition(s)
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:42,950 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher:272 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Sending READ_UNCOMMITTED IncrementalFetchRequest(toSend=(hidden-topic-name-59), toForget=(), toReplace=(), implied=(), canUseTopicIds=True) to broker b-2.pdx-lev-d01-c0-amak-ch.ghdxjf.c3.kafka.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:9096 (id: 2 rack: usw2-az3)
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:42,950 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient:521 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Sending FETCH request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=FETCH, apiVersion=12, clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, correlationId=1091, headerVersion=2) and timeout 30000 to node 2: FetchRequestData(clusterId=null, replicaId=-1, maxWaitMs=500, minBytes=1, maxBytes=52428800, isolationLevel=0, sessionId=749023988, sessionEpoch=275, topics=[FetchTopic(topic='hidden-topic-name', topicId=WBNmnPqGQJ6J7bXqyiwMXg, partitions=[FetchPartition(partition=59, currentLeaderEpoch=108, fetchOffset=809302, lastFetchedEpoch=-1, logStartOffset=-1, partitionMaxBytes=1048576)])], forgottenTopicsData=[], rackId='')
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:42,966 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient:879 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Received FETCH response from node 2 for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=FETCH, apiVersion=12, clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, correlationId=1091, headerVersion=2): FetchResponseData(throttleTimeMs=0, errorCode=0, sessionId=749023988, responses=[FetchableTopicResponse(topic='hidden-topic-name', topicId=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA, partitions=[PartitionData(partitionIndex=59, errorCode=0, highWatermark=1137776, lastStableOffset=1137776, logStartOffset=640097, divergingEpoch=EpochEndOffset(epoch=-1, endOffset=-1), currentLeader=LeaderIdAndEpoch(leaderId=-1, leaderEpoch=-1), snapshotId=SnapshotId(endOffset=-1, epoch=-1), abortedTransactions=null, preferredReadReplica=-1, records=MemoryRecords(size=1048576, buffer=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=1048576 cap=1048579]))])])
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:42,966 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.FetchSessionHandler:584 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Node 2 sent an incremental fetch response with throttleTimeMs = 0 for session 749023988 with 1 response partition(s)
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:42,966 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher:324 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Fetch READ_UNCOMMITTED at offset 809302 for partition hidden-topic-name-59 returned fetch data PartitionData(partitionIndex=59, errorCode=0, highWatermark=1137776, lastStableOffset=1137776, logStartOffset=640097, divergingEpoch=EpochEndOffset(epoch=-1, endOffset=-1), currentLeader=LeaderIdAndEpoch(leaderId=-1, leaderEpoch=-1), snapshotId=SnapshotId(endOffset=-1, epoch=-1), abortedTransactions=null, preferredReadReplica=-1, records=MemoryRecords(size=1048576, buffer=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=1048576 cap=1048579]))
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:42,979 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher:1235 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Added READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch request for partition hidden-topic-name-59 at position FetchPosition{offset=822921, offsetEpoch=Optional[85], currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[b-2.pdx-lev-d01-c0-amak-ch.ghdxjf.c3.kafka.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:9096 (id: 2 rack: usw2-az3)], epoch=108}} to node b-2.pdx-lev-d01-c0-amak-ch.ghdxjf.c3.kafka.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:9096 (id: 2 rack: usw2-az3)
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:42,979 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.FetchSessionHandler:351 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Built incremental fetch (sessionId=749023988, epoch=276) for node 2. Added 0 partition(s), altered 1 partition(s), removed 0 partition(s), replaced 0 partition(s) out of 1 partition(s)
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:42,979 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher:272 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Sending READ_UNCOMMITTED IncrementalFetchRequest(toSend=(hidden-topic-name-59), toForget=(), toReplace=(), implied=(), canUseTopicIds=True) to broker b-2.pdx-lev-d01-c0-amak-ch.ghdxjf.c3.kafka.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:9096 (id: 2 rack: usw2-az3)
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:42,979 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient:521 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Sending FETCH request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=FETCH, apiVersion=12, clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, correlationId=1092, headerVersion=2) and timeout 30000 to node 2: FetchRequestData(clusterId=null, replicaId=-1, maxWaitMs=500, minBytes=1, maxBytes=52428800, isolationLevel=0, sessionId=749023988, sessionEpoch=276, topics=[FetchTopic(topic='hidden-topic-name', topicId=WBNmnPqGQJ6J7bXqyiwMXg, partitions=[FetchPartition(partition=59, currentLeaderEpoch=108, fetchOffset=822921, lastFetchedEpoch=-1, logStartOffset=-1, partitionMaxBytes=1048576)])], forgottenTopicsData=[], rackId='')
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,002 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient:879 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Received FETCH response from node 2 for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=FETCH, apiVersion=12, clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, correlationId=1092, headerVersion=2): FetchResponseData(throttleTimeMs=0, errorCode=0, sessionId=749023988, responses=[FetchableTopicResponse(topic='hidden-topic-name', topicId=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA, partitions=[PartitionData(partitionIndex=59, errorCode=0, highWatermark=1137776, lastStableOffset=1137776, logStartOffset=640097, divergingEpoch=EpochEndOffset(epoch=-1, endOffset=-1), currentLeader=LeaderIdAndEpoch(leaderId=-1, leaderEpoch=-1), snapshotId=SnapshotId(endOffset=-1, epoch=-1), abortedTransactions=null, preferredReadReplica=-1, records=MemoryRecords(size=1048576, buffer=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=1048576 cap=1048579]))])])
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,003 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.FetchSessionHandler:584 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Node 2 sent an incremental fetch response with throttleTimeMs = 0 for session 749023988 with 1 response partition(s)
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,003 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher:324 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Fetch READ_UNCOMMITTED at offset 822921 for partition hidden-topic-name-59 returned fetch data PartitionData(partitionIndex=59, errorCode=0, highWatermark=1137776, lastStableOffset=1137776, logStartOffset=640097, divergingEpoch=EpochEndOffset(epoch=-1, endOffset=-1), currentLeader=LeaderIdAndEpoch(leaderId=-1, leaderEpoch=-1), snapshotId=SnapshotId(endOffset=-1, epoch=-1), abortedTransactions=null, preferredReadReplica=-1, records=MemoryRecords(size=1048576, buffer=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=1048576 cap=1048579]))
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,015 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher:1235 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Added READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch request for partition hidden-topic-name-59 at position FetchPosition{offset=835800, offsetEpoch=Optional[92], currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[b-2.pdx-lev-d01-c0-amak-ch.ghdxjf.c3.kafka.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:9096 (id: 2 rack: usw2-az3)], epoch=108}} to node b-2.pdx-lev-d01-c0-amak-ch.ghdxjf.c3.kafka.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:9096 (id: 2 rack: usw2-az3)
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,015 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.FetchSessionHandler:351 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Built incremental fetch (sessionId=749023988, epoch=277) for node 2. Added 0 partition(s), altered 1 partition(s), removed 0 partition(s), replaced 0 partition(s) out of 1 partition(s)
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,015 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher:272 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Sending READ_UNCOMMITTED IncrementalFetchRequest(toSend=(hidden-topic-name-59), toForget=(), toReplace=(), implied=(), canUseTopicIds=True) to broker b-2.pdx-lev-d01-c0-amak-ch.ghdxjf.c3.kafka.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:9096 (id: 2 rack: usw2-az3)
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,016 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient:521 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Sending FETCH request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=FETCH, apiVersion=12, clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, correlationId=1093, headerVersion=2) and timeout 30000 to node 2: FetchRequestData(clusterId=null, replicaId=-1, maxWaitMs=500, minBytes=1, maxBytes=52428800, isolationLevel=0, sessionId=749023988, sessionEpoch=277, topics=[FetchTopic(topic='hidden-topic-name', topicId=WBNmnPqGQJ6J7bXqyiwMXg, partitions=[FetchPartition(partition=59, currentLeaderEpoch=108, fetchOffset=835800, lastFetchedEpoch=-1, logStartOffset=-1, partitionMaxBytes=1048576)])], forgottenTopicsData=[], rackId='')
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,034 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient:879 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Received FETCH response from node 2 for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=FETCH, apiVersion=12, clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, correlationId=1093, headerVersion=2): FetchResponseData(throttleTimeMs=0, errorCode=0, sessionId=749023988, responses=[FetchableTopicResponse(topic='hidden-topic-name', topicId=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA, partitions=[PartitionData(partitionIndex=59, errorCode=0, highWatermark=1137776, lastStableOffset=1137776, logStartOffset=640097, divergingEpoch=EpochEndOffset(epoch=-1, endOffset=-1), currentLeader=LeaderIdAndEpoch(leaderId=-1, leaderEpoch=-1), snapshotId=SnapshotId(endOffset=-1, epoch=-1), abortedTransactions=null, preferredReadReplica=-1, records=MemoryRecords(size=1048576, buffer=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=1048576 cap=1048579]))])])
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,034 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.FetchSessionHandler:584 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Node 2 sent an incremental fetch response with throttleTimeMs = 0 for session 749023988 with 1 response partition(s)
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,034 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher:324 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Fetch READ_UNCOMMITTED at offset 835800 for partition hidden-topic-name-59 returned fetch data PartitionData(partitionIndex=59, errorCode=0, highWatermark=1137776, lastStableOffset=1137776, logStartOffset=640097, divergingEpoch=EpochEndOffset(epoch=-1, endOffset=-1), currentLeader=LeaderIdAndEpoch(leaderId=-1, leaderEpoch=-1), snapshotId=SnapshotId(endOffset=-1, epoch=-1), abortedTransactions=null, preferredReadReplica=-1, records=MemoryRecords(size=1048576, buffer=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=1048576 cap=1048579]))
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,048 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher:1235 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Added READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch request for partition hidden-topic-name-59 at position FetchPosition{offset=850643, offsetEpoch=Optional[93], currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[b-2.pdx-lev-d01-c0-amak-ch.ghdxjf.c3.kafka.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:9096 (id: 2 rack: usw2-az3)], epoch=108}} to node b-2.pdx-lev-d01-c0-amak-ch.ghdxjf.c3.kafka.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:9096 (id: 2 rack: usw2-az3)
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,048 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.FetchSessionHandler:351 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Built incremental fetch (sessionId=749023988, epoch=278) for node 2. Added 0 partition(s), altered 1 partition(s), removed 0 partition(s), replaced 0 partition(s) out of 1 partition(s)
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,048 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher:272 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Sending READ_UNCOMMITTED IncrementalFetchRequest(toSend=(hidden-topic-name-59), toForget=(), toReplace=(), implied=(), canUseTopicIds=True) to broker b-2.pdx-lev-d01-c0-amak-ch.ghdxjf.c3.kafka.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:9096 (id: 2 rack: usw2-az3)
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,048 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient:521 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Sending FETCH request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=FETCH, apiVersion=12, clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, correlationId=1094, headerVersion=2) and timeout 30000 to node 2: FetchRequestData(clusterId=null, replicaId=-1, maxWaitMs=500, minBytes=1, maxBytes=52428800, isolationLevel=0, sessionId=749023988, sessionEpoch=278, topics=[FetchTopic(topic='hidden-topic-name', topicId=WBNmnPqGQJ6J7bXqyiwMXg, partitions=[FetchPartition(partition=59, currentLeaderEpoch=108, fetchOffset=850643, lastFetchedEpoch=-1, logStartOffset=-1, partitionMaxBytes=1048576)])], forgottenTopicsData=[], rackId='')
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,061 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient:879 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Received FETCH response from node 2 for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=FETCH, apiVersion=12, clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, correlationId=1094, headerVersion=2): FetchResponseData(throttleTimeMs=0, errorCode=0, sessionId=749023988, responses=[FetchableTopicResponse(topic='hidden-topic-name', topicId=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA, partitions=[PartitionData(partitionIndex=59, errorCode=0, highWatermark=1137776, lastStableOffset=1137776, logStartOffset=640097, divergingEpoch=EpochEndOffset(epoch=-1, endOffset=-1), currentLeader=LeaderIdAndEpoch(leaderId=-1, leaderEpoch=-1), snapshotId=SnapshotId(endOffset=-1, epoch=-1), abortedTransactions=null, preferredReadReplica=-1, records=MemoryRecords(size=1048576, buffer=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=1048576 cap=1048579]))])])
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,061 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.FetchSessionHandler:584 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Node 2 sent an incremental fetch response with throttleTimeMs = 0 for session 749023988 with 1 response partition(s)
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,061 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher:324 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Fetch READ_UNCOMMITTED at offset 850643 for partition hidden-topic-name-59 returned fetch data PartitionData(partitionIndex=59, errorCode=0, highWatermark=1137776, lastStableOffset=1137776, logStartOffset=640097, divergingEpoch=EpochEndOffset(epoch=-1, endOffset=-1), currentLeader=LeaderIdAndEpoch(leaderId=-1, leaderEpoch=-1), snapshotId=SnapshotId(endOffset=-1, epoch=-1), abortedTransactions=null, preferredReadReplica=-1, records=MemoryRecords(size=1048576, buffer=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=1048576 cap=1048579]))
INFO  | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,065 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.c.KafkaConsumer:1078 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
INFO  | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,066 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:693 - Metrics scheduler closed
INFO  | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,066 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:697 - Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
INFO  | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,066 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:703 - Metrics reporters closed
INFO  | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,071 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser:83 - App info kafka.consumer for hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer unregistered
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,071 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.c.c.KafkaConsumer:2425 - [Consumer clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-global-consumer, groupId=null] Kafka consumer has been closed
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,072 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.s.p.i.GlobalStateManagerImpl:380 - global-stream-thread [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread] Closing global storage engine hidden-storage-engine
INFO  | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,072 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.s.p.i.GlobalStreamThread:167 - global-stream-thread [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread] State transition from CREATED to PENDING_SHUTDOWN
INFO  | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,074 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.s.p.i.GlobalStreamThread:167 - global-stream-thread [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread] State transition from PENDING_SHUTDOWN to DEAD
ERROR | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,075 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.s.KafkaStreams:672 - stream-client [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac] Global thread has died. The streams application or client will now close to ERROR.
INFO  | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,075 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.s.KafkaStreams:341 - stream-client [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac] State transition from REBALANCING to PENDING_ERROR
ERROR | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,076 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread]   [] o.a.k.s.p.i.GlobalStreamThread:297 - global-stream-thread [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-GlobalStreamThread] Error happened during initialization of the global state store; this thread has shutdown.
INFO  | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,078 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-CloseThread]   [] o.a.k.s.KafkaStreams:1364 - stream-client [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac] Shutting down 0 stream threads
INFO  | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,078 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-CloseThread]   [] o.a.k.s.KafkaStreams:1386 - stream-client [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac] Shutdown 0 stream threads complete
INFO  | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,078 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-CloseThread]   [] o.a.k.s.KafkaStreams:1389 - stream-client [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac] Shutting down the global stream threads
INFO  | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,078 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-CloseThread]   [] o.a.k.s.KafkaStreams:1404 - stream-client [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac] Shutdown global stream threads complete
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,079 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-CloseThread]   [] o.a.k.c.a.KafkaAdminClient:644 - [AdminClient clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-admin] Initiating close operation.
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,079 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-CloseThread]   [] o.a.k.c.a.KafkaAdminClient:660 - [AdminClient clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-admin] Waiting for the I/O thread to exit. Hard shutdown in 31536000000 ms.
INFO  | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,079 | [kafka-admin-client-thread | hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-admin]   [] o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser:83 - App info kafka.admin.client for hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-admin unregistered
INFO  | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,080 | [kafka-admin-client-thread | hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-admin]   [] o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:693 - Metrics scheduler closed
INFO  | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,080 | [kafka-admin-client-thread | hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-admin]   [] o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:697 - Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
INFO  | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,080 | [kafka-admin-client-thread | hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-admin]   [] o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:703 - Metrics reporters closed
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,080 | [kafka-admin-client-thread | hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-admin]   [] o.a.k.c.a.KafkaAdminClient:1363 - [AdminClient clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-admin] Exiting AdminClientRunnable thread.
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,080 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-CloseThread]   [] o.a.k.c.a.KafkaAdminClient:669 - [AdminClient clientId=hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-admin] Kafka admin client closed.
INFO  | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,081 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-CloseThread]   [] o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:693 - Metrics scheduler closed
INFO  | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,081 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-CloseThread]   [] o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:697 - Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
INFO  | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,081 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-CloseThread]   [] o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:703 - Metrics reporters closed
INFO  | 2023-07-20 21:58:43,081 | [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac-CloseThread]   [] o.a.k.s.KafkaStreams:341 - stream-client [hidden-service-name-08cd3ea1-e5de-4ee4-92da-0fa4ed82aaac] State transition from PENDING_ERROR to ERROR
DEBUG | 2023-07-20 21:58:52,252 | [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper]   [] o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:441 - Closing connections idle longer than 60000 MILLISECONDS
```

Also trying to open a JIRA for Kafka project as well. Just waiting to get access. But strongly recommend adding a catch block in the method above to log any relevant exceptions.

Expected state store restoration to happen successfully, but it did not happen.
Enabled debug logging to see if there will be any more logs but it didn't help.

Comment: Did you try to register an uncaught exception handler to get a hold on the exception? I agree, that that KS should log it; thanks for filing a ticket.